# preg_match Follower Count on Google+

Tags: php

I searched online for a while and there is no way right now to get the Follower count of Google+ Profiles.

My plan now was to get the webpage code with file_get_contents and then to use preg_match.

But I´m using this function the first time and I have no clue how to use it. I read online a bit about it but I dont understand it.

The pattern is quite simple. There is a Number with periods/dots (.) on every thousand, a space and then the word "Follower".

How can I express that as the pattern for preg_match ?

And I read something about preg_replace which I could then use to replace the periods/dots (.) with nothing. Am I right ?

Thanks a lot !

Regards

Selfster

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please remove all the story from your question and keep **only** whats relevant - input/output/code/what have you tried/where exactly your problem is. Thanks :)

Comment: You can almost certainly do this with Google's API. https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people#resource

Comment: I saw that already. Sadly it´s not possible. 
I tried it a lot of times. 
This would be the function : https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId/people/collection

But it´s not possibe somehow. The collection parameter has two options : visible and connected. Both are not giving any results. 
Visible : "Only allowed to fetch the authenticated user's visible circles."
Connected :"Invalid Value"

And online a lot of people are complaining about it as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/) for that.
Here is the [reference](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/).

Comment: Please read the comment under the intial post. 
I answered that already.

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get
Here you can try it. 
circledByCount,plusOneCount would be the fields, but there is no Output to those.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a fool proof method but it works.

```
$test = file_get_contents("https://plus.google.com/+SundarPichai");
$res = preg_match_all("%\b([\.\,\d]+) followers%",$test, $output, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($output);
```

The regex `"%\b([\.\,\d]+) followers%"` starts with a non alphanumeric character and than takes commas and points (depending on the localization).
I think it by default falls back to the American (thats why there are comma's) and than followed by a space and the word `followers`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This works. But how does it work with the pattern ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a Google API key, then it works like this:

id is like 103382528845345115881

key like AIzaSyAqlZ1MJSGXMSs8a5WbfvLpZTGJeHLVc2w

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/<id>?key=<key>
```

The field you need is this: `"circledByCount": 10,`

Shortes form to use is like this:

```
<?php
$followers = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$followers = isset($followers['circledByCount'])
    ? $followers['circledByCount'] : 0;
```

Only works when the followers amount is publicily visible.